# Ошибка 404 spring mvc + tomcat

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

Делаю по учебному видео spring mvc проект с использование сервера Tomcat.

При запуске проекта открывается вкладка с ошибкой 404.

SDK 19
Tomcat 9.0.29
IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2023.1.3
Tomcat 9.0.29
5.2.1.RELEASE
Thymeleaf 3.0.11.RELEASE
Javax.servlet 4.0.1

Также пробовал другие вариации версий из комментариев под видео (которые работали у других) у меня всё также, иногда вообще переставал запускаться сервер.

Ошибка

[image: Ошибка]

Структура проекта

[image: Структура проекта]

MySpringMvcDispatcherSerlvetIntitializer.java

```
public class MySpringMvcDispatcherSerlvetIntitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{SpringConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
}
```

Spring.java

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("ru.alishev.springcourse")
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    public SpringConfig(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }
}
```

HelloController.java

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {
    @GetMapping("/hello-world")
    public String sayHello() {
        return "hello_world";
    }
}
```

hello_world.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>My app</title>
</head>

<body>

<p>Hello world!</p>

</body>

</html>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>ru.alishev.springcourse</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-mvc-app-java-config</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>spring-mvc-app1 Maven Webapp</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>

    <spring.version>5.2.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
      <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>spring-mvc-app1</finalName>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Логи

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\tomcat-9.0.29\apache-tomcat-9.0.29\bin\catalina.bat" run
[2023-07-13 07:14:37,071] Artifact spring-mvc-app-java-config:war exploded: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\Mikhail\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2023.1\tomcat\362e4ceb-a66b-484f-aab0-81eab5e684bf"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Program Files (x86)\tomcat-9.0.29\apache-tomcat-9.0.29"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Program Files (x86)\tomcat-9.0.29\apache-tomcat-9.0.29\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Users\Mikhail\.jdks\openjdk-19.0.2"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Program Files (x86)\tomcat-9.0.29\apache-tomcat-9.0.29\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\tomcat-9.0.29\apache-tomcat-9.0.29\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS:  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
13-Jul-2023 07:14:37.609 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.29
13-Jul-2023 07:14:37.610 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Nov 16 2019 17:29:07 UTC
13-Jul-2023 07:14:37.611 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 9.0.29.0
13-Jul-2023 07:14:37.611 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 10
13-Jul-2023 07:14:37.611 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.0
13-Jul-2023 07:14:37.611 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
13-Jul-2023 07:14:37.611 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Users\Mikhail\.jdks\openjdk-19.0.2
13-Jul-2023 07:14:37.611 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           19.0.2+7-44
13-Jul-2023 07:14:37.611 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
13-Jul-2023 07:14:37.611 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\Mikhail\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2023.1\tomcat\362e4ceb-a66b-484f-aab0-81eab5e684bf
13-Jul-2023 07:14:37.611 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files (x86)\tomcat-9.0.29\apache-tomcat-9.0.29
13-Jul-2023 07:14:37.612 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
13-Jul-2023 07:14:37.612 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
13-Jul-2023 07:14:37.612 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
13-Jul-2023 07:14:37.612 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\Mikhail\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2023.1\tomcat\362e4ceb-a66b-484f-aab0-81eab5e684bf\conf\logging.properties
13-Jul-2023 07:14:37.612 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
13-Jul-2023 07:14:37.612 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
13-Jul-2023 07:14:37.612 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
13-Jul-2023 07:14:37.612 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
13-Jul-2023 07:14:37.613 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=C:\Users\Mikhail\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2023.1\tomcat\362e4ceb-a66b-484f-aab0-81eab5e684bf\jmxremote.password
13-Jul-2023 07:14:37.613 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=C:\Users\Mikhail\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2023.1\tomcat\362e4ceb-a66b-484f-aab0-81eab5e684bf\jmxremote.access
13-Jul-2023 07:14:37.613 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
13-Jul-2023 07:14:37.613 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
13-Jul-2023 07:14:37.613 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
13-Jul-2023 07:14:37.613 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
13-Jul-2023 07:14:37.613 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Mikhail\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2023.1\tomcat\362e4ceb-a66b-484f-aab0-81eab5e684bf
13-Jul-2023 07:14:37.613 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files (x86)\tomcat-9.0.29\apache-tomcat-9.0.29
13-Jul-2023 07:14:37.613 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files (x86)\tomcat-9.0.29\apache-tomcat-9.0.29\temp
13-Jul-2023 07:14:37.613 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Users\Mikhail\.jdks\openjdk-19.0.2\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Users\Mikhail\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Mikhail\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\Mikhail\.dotnet\tools;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.3\bin;;.]
13-Jul-2023 07:14:37.732 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
13-Jul-2023 07:14:37.767 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
13-Jul-2023 07:14:37.769 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [291] milliseconds
13-Jul-2023 07:14:37.794 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
13-Jul-2023 07:14:37.794 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.29]
13-Jul-2023 07:14:37.801 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
13-Jul-2023 07:14:37.808 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
13-Jul-2023 07:14:37.810 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [40] milliseconds
Connected to server
[2023-07-13 07:14:38,156] Artifact spring-mvc-app-java-config:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
13-Jul-2023 07:14:39.209 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
[2023-07-13 07:14:40,082] Artifact spring-mvc-app-java-config:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2023-07-13 07:14:40,083] Artifact spring-mvc-app-java-config:war exploded: Deploy took 1,927 milliseconds
13-Jul-2023 07:14:47.811 INFO [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory РЈСЃС‚Р°РЅРѕРІРєР° РІРµР± РїСЂРёР»РѕР¶РµРЅРёСЏ РІ РїР°РїРєСѓ [C:\Program Files (x86)\tomcat-9.0.29\apache-tomcat-9.0.29\webapps\manager]
13-Jul-2023 07:14:47.852 INFO [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files (x86)\tomcat-9.0.29\apache-tomcat-9.0.29\webapps\manager] has finished in [41] ms
```